# Is there any audio DSP without biquad constraint?

Tags: filters, digital-filters, biquad

I found a codec with audio DSP, [ADAU1772](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADAU1772.pdf). It supports 32 **biquads**, that is $32\cdot5=160$ parameters.

I need to calculate filter coefficients **on-line**. The result is in transfer function form, i.e.,

$$[a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{m-1}, b_0, b_1, \cdots, b_{n-1}]$$

If I want to use an audio DSP, I must transform the result into **SOS matrix**.

In MATLAB, here is a function `tf2sos` does the job. It needs to solve high-order equations to find poles and zeros. Maybe it's difficult for MCUs.

- Assume number of coefficients $m=n=32$, is there any method I can write all the 64 coefficients directly into a chip and make it work?
- Or is there any audio DSP chips without biquad-structure constraint?